# LLDB swift print object

Tags: swift, lldb

Im a little dumfounded with how to use LLDB to inspect an object in a swift project. In this particular case I'm using NSJSONSerializer to serialize a small chunk of JSON and I'd like to inspect the value.  In Xcode 5.1 this was super simple, just type "po json" at the lldb prompt and I'd get what I wanted.  Now the commands po and print fail me by printing out mostly garbage.  I even tried calling the description property because that works with some swift types but that still doesn't work.  As a last resort I used an expression with a println statement and finally that works.  Surely there must be a better simpler way? Here is the output of LLDB:

```
(lldb) print json
(AnyObject?) $R4 = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x00007ff05c0c49d0 ->     0x0000000107ef32c8 (void *)0x0000000107ef32f0: __NSCFDictionary)
(lldb) po json
(instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x00007ff05c0c49d0 -> 0x0000000107ef32c8 (void  *)0x0000000107ef32f0: __NSCFDictionary)
 {
  instance_type = 0x00007ff05c0c49d0 -> 0x0000000107ef32c8 (void *)0x0000000107ef32f0:  __NSCFDictionary
}
(lldb) print json.description?
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: 'Optional<AnyObject>' does not have a member named 'description'
json.description?
^    ~~~~~~~~~~~

(lldb) po json.description?
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: 'Optional<AnyObject>' does not have a member named    'description'
json.description?
^    ~~~~~~~~~~~
(lldb) expression
Enter expressions, then terminate with an empty line to evaluate:
1 println(json)
2 
Optional({
    errors =     {
        "authorizations.provider_user_id" =         (
            "has already been taken"
        );
    };
})
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
(lldb) expr -O -d run -- json!
```

The fact that "po" does not exactly work in the same way it does in ObjC is a known limitation. Explicitly unwrapping the optional, and allowing dynamic type resolution on the unwrapped value should work